What does it mean to be "truly" asynchronous?
Reading the Proactor pattern paper, specifically this part:

I/O Completion Ports in Windows NT: The Windows NT operating system implements the Proactor pattern. Various Asynchronous Operations such as accepting new network connections, reading and writing to files and sockets, and transmission of files across a network connection are supported by Windows NT. The operating system is the Asynchronous Operation Processor. Results of the operations are queued up at the I/O completion port (which plays the role of the Completion Dispatcher).
The UNIX AIO Family of Asynchronous I/O Operations: On some real-time POSIX platforms, the Proactor pattern is implemented by the aio family of APIs [9]. These OS features are very similar to the ones described above for Windows NT. One difference is that UNIX signals can be used to implement a truly asynchronous Completion Dispatcher (the Windows NT API is not truly asynchronous).

What does it mean that Unix Signals can be used to implement "truly" asynchronous and that Windows NT API is not truly async? What makes it truly?

please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78904426/what-does-it-mean-to-be-truly-asynchronous-in-the-proactor-pattern "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

What I make from the wording (signals) is that Unix will trigger an event when there is new data to be read whereas Windows will give you a file handle you can use to actively poll for new data using your own thread. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports .

Ask yourself what it takes to be a true Scotsman. There's a difference in asking what is true asynchrony and asking what this author is claiming to be true asynchrony.

Here it just means that while the I/O operations themselves may be asynchronous, the completion events are dispatched synchronously in Windows (ie, when you check the completion port).
UNIX signals are asynchronous in the sense that they can interrupt your existing thread of control, invoke a signal handler in its own context, and then resume your normal execution.
In practice it's often easier to use ppoll/pselect/sigtimedwait or some other synchronous method, rather than trying to do something both useful and async-signal-safe in a handler.
--
NB. Whether this is more "truly" asynchronous isn't really an interesting question, because it just devolves into a "no true Scotsman" argument about the One True Meaning of Asynchrony.
All that matters is that the original authors considered asynchronous operations with asynchronous delivery of completions "more asynchronous" than asynchronous operations with synchronous delivery of completions.

Thank you. That's a great answer.

If you take a look at 1:34 of this video and a few minutes after : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfrcHfkLgGI&t=156s it seems like he's saying Windows does a better job of supporting async IO compared with UNIX, while from the description that was in the original paper I got the impression of the opposite. Did I understand that wrong, or is this more of a difference in timing between when the paper was written and the video and both were true at their time?

I think it's fair to say that POSIX aio implementations have often not been as "natively asynchronous" as the Windows equivalent - the glibc implementation is done entirely in userspace by spinning up background threads. Linux does have a couple of truly async file I/O interfaces, but IIUC they're not used by the glibc implementation of POSIX aio.
